# Solving the nonlinear ODE: $ \frac{1}{y^{\prime}}+\left(x-\frac{y}{y^{\prime}}\right)^{2}+1=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{1}{y^{\prime}}+\left(x-\frac{y}{y^{\prime}}\right)^{2}+1=0$$

I am trying to solve this non-linear ODE and have tried all sorts of substitutions; any hints on how I should progress?

Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid `$$` and `\displaystyle` in the title!

Answer (score 3):

Let $y = a x + b$, then $y' = a$, and you have the equation:

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{1}{a} + \left(x - x - \dfrac{b}{a}\right)^2 + 1 &  =  0\\ \dfrac{1}{a} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} + 1 &  =  0 \\ a + b^2 + a^2 &  =  0 \\ \left(a + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + b^2 & =  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \end{align} $$

So the solutions are lines with coefficients lying on a circle

To quickly check if there are any more solutions, we may wish to differentiate the equation and see if $y'' = 0$.  Multiplying first by $(y')^2$, we have

$$(1 - 2xy)y' + (x^2 + 1)(y')^2 + y^2 = 0 $$

Differentiating,

$$(-2y)y' - 2x (y')^2 + (1 - 2xy) y'' + 2x(y')^2 + 2(x^2 + 1)y' y'' + 2y y' = 0 $$

Simplifying,

$$(1 - 2xy)y'' + 2(x^2 + 1)y' y'' = 0 $$

Leaving us with

$$y'' = 0$$ or $$1 - 2xy + 2(x^2 + 1)y' = 0 $$

In the second case, we have an ODE which we can solve with an integrating factor

$$y' - \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} y = \frac{-1}{2(x^2 + 1)}$$

This gives us equations of the form $$y = -\frac{x}{2} + C \sqrt{1 + x^2}$$

Substituting this back into the original equation, we see this has a solution when $4 C^2 = 1$, or when $C = \pm \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is good but does not by itself rule out solutions that are not of the form $y=ax+b$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, hope I fixed it up a little bit.  I don't really know how to handle the case where sometimes $y''=0$ and other times $1 - 2xy + (2x^2 + 1)y' = 0$.  I suppose there is some argument to show we don't need to worry about it flipping between the two.

Comment: The curve $x=\frac{1}{4y}-y$ is also a solution. I think our answers are the same now, but you can handle the second case in your answer by linearly combining it with the original equation.

Comment: Also, there are more complicated solutions where a straight line intersects this last curve tangentially, which then takes over. And may even move on to another straight line.

Comment: Ah I see, combining the equations up piecewise to meet the condition that it is differentiable.  The possible values of $y'$ before were $a$ where $a$ lies in a circle centred at $(-1/2, 0)$ with radius $1/2$ so a could take on all values between $-1$ and $0$ (except $0$).  The derivatives of these other curves however are $-\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$ which for the most part takes on values outside of this range except a small region of the curve $\frac{-x}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{2}$ which has derivatives in $[-1, 0)$ in the region $x \in [-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, 0)$

Comment: ...and since the derivative of that function is 1-1, that change can only ever happen at most two times.  ie) Either we have line-curve-line or curve-line

Comment: Experimenting with GeoGebra, it appears *every* line of the form you found will be tangent to the hyperbola at one point.  Maximal solution curves (which might not be functions) are (1) the hyperbola together with the line $y=-x$, (2) one arm of the hyperbola together with some tangent line to the other arm, (3) one whole arm together with the other arm spliced with a tangent line in a way that crosses $y=-x$, (4) one whole arm together with the other arm spliced with a tangent line in a way that would not cross $y=-x$ together with $y=-x$. This is why textbooks avoid nonlinear equations :)

Answer (score 2):

Try solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ instead, to avoid fractions. If $x'$ means $dx/dy$, then we have

$$x'+\left(x-x'y\right)^{2}+1=0$$

Differentiating,

$$x''-2\left(x-x'y\right)(x''y)=0$$

$$x''(1-2xy+2x'y^2)=0$$

Now at any point, either the second derivative $x''$ is $0$ or $1-2xy+2x'y^2=0$. Away from $y=0$, the latter equation is equivalent to $x'=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2y^2}$ which is first order linear.

If $x''=0$ in a neighborhood, then in that neighborhood the solution is a straight line, and @muzzlator's answer puts constraints on the coefficients.

If $x'=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2y^2}$ in some neighborhood, then we can combine this with the original equation to get

$$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2y^2}+\left(x-\left(\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2y^2}\right)y\right)^{2}+1=0$$

$$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2y^2}+\frac{1}{4y^2}+1=0$$

$$x-\frac{1}{4y}+y=0$$

$$x=\frac{1}{4y}-y$$

which also checks against the original equation. The full solution set consists of all the lines from @muzzlator's answer, spliced in all possible differentiable ways with the curve $x=\frac{1}{4y}-y$.

Comment: +1, nice way of answering it.  If you're still interested, I put a few comments under my answer regarding how that splicing is possible.  There aren't many ways at all by the restricted range of the derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, we can see that $y=-x$ is one of the solutions because, $y'=-1$ which implies
$$\frac{1}{y^{\prime}}+\left(x-\frac{y}{y^{\prime}}\right)^{2}+1
=-1+(x-x)^2+1=0.$$